# Why is it better to use evolutionary algorithms than OLS for solving index tracking problem?

Tags: portfolio-management, portfolio-optimization, optimization, index, tracking-error

I am currently using different optimization algorithms for finding constrained portfolio that best replicate choosen index. So i have a optimization task to minimize tracking error. I wonder why every paper use evolutionary algorithms, particle swarm optimizers or to lesser extent simmulated annealing or bayesian optimization, when using standard OLS with constrains should suffice as it is already minimizing similar measure analyticaly, ergo more preicisely. My comparison have also shown that PSO or bayesian optimization wont converge and gives worse recommended parameters than OLS. Why are they more popular ?

Comment: Some people have problems to solve and they look for mathematical techniques to solve them. Some people know fancy mathematical techniques and look for problems to solve, so they can publish articles in journals showing how innovative they are in applying new techniques.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would have been helpful had you provided links to those papers.

But in general,
you need to distinguish between the optimisation
*model*, and the *numerical technique* used to solve
the model.

Suppose you wanted to estimate a linear regression,
with the mean squared residual as the criterion of fit,
and without further constraints. This is a model. Now
you can solve this model via a `QR` decomposition, say;
or you can use a heuristic such as Differential
Evolution or Particle Swarm Optimisation
(PSO). If done properly, all techniques will give you
exactly the same fit (up to numerical precision). That
is because they all solve the same model, and it is a
model that is easy to solve. (Btw, you cannot use
Least-Squares techniques when you have inequality
constraints.)

The advantage of using heuristics such as PSO is that
you can now solve other, more complex models: you may, for instance,
include cardinality constraints or UCITS (5/10/40) constraints. See for instance ["The
Threshold Accepting Heuristic for Index Tracking"](https://ssrn.com/abstract=1317358)
 or ["Exact and Heuristic Approaches for the Index Tracking
Problem with UCITS Constraints"](https://ssrn.com/abstract=2066672).

Comment: Hi: Unless I'm mis-understanding, minimizing tracking error of portfolio versus fund is a quadratic optimization problem so I don't see how you could use OLS to solve it ?

Comment: thanks for reply, maybe the constraints are what limits OLS. @markleeds you can use OLS to solve tracking error when y is index returns and explanatory variables are returns of assets choosen for portfolio. Estimeted model coefficients are weights of assets in a portfolio. Estimation of intercept must be ommited

Comment: @SquintRook: Thanks but can you write out your formulation. The standard tracking error problem is quadratic ( return is linear but variance is quadratic ) so you must be formulating it differently than the standard approach.

Comment: @mark leeds: in the appendix of http://enricoschumann.net/files/style_analysis.pdf, there are examples for unconstrained
optimisation models that can be solved with a QP or a
Least-Squares method. You could still use a
Least-Squares method when you have linear equality
restrictions (such as the sum of coefficients should be
one), but not inequality restrictions (such as
nonnegativity).

Comment: @Enrico Schumann: Thanks for your examples but what does $X$ represent in those two cases. Maybe they are return exposures to some underlying factor model  ? So X represents the loadings that the target fund has with respect to that factor model ? Then, the resulting $\beta_{i}$ are the weights that should be used for each of the factors ? Thanks.

Comment: For the case here, the columns of `X` could hold the return scenarios of the assets that are to replicate the index. `y` holds the index returns; the $\beta$-values are the weights.

Comment: A number of portfolio-selection models can actually be handled as regressions. For instance http://comisef.wikidot.com/tutorial:minimumvariance or http://comisef.wikidot.com/tutorial:tangencyportfolio

Comment: @Enrico Schumann: you mean that, if X was 3 by 10 and there were stocks, bonds and cash as assets, then column 1 would be one scenario for the returns of stocks, bonds and cash,  column 2 would be a second scenario, etc ? In that case,  what does  $y = X^ \prime \beta$? represent. Assuming $\beta$ is 3 by 1, then the $y$ vector is  10 by 1. Apologies for confusion and thanks.

Comment: The result holds the returns of the portfolio $\beta$ in the different scenarios. The idea is then to choose the $\beta$ so that $y$ (the index returns) are as similar as possible to $X\beta$. (Since this is getting slightly off-topic, perhaps another forum, such as https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/R-SIG-Finance/ , is  better suited for this discussion?)

Comment: @Enrico Schumann: Thanks for explanation. I get what you're doing so no need to move it to R-sig-finance. Note that your formulation doesn't do anything with variance ( just mimicing return ) so it's not really a true index tracking tool.  My apologies for all the bothers.

Comment: A tracking portfolio is a linear combination of assets,
whose returns should closely match those of the
index. To compute weights for the tracking portfolio, a common formulation is to
minimise the variance of the return differences between
index and portfolio; tracking error is usually defined
as this variance. The formulations via an equality-only-constrained QP and via a linear regression do exactly that (because that is how you fit a regression with OLS); they are exactly equivalent.